# Node get posted variables via body-parser

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I'm trying to retrieve the posted variables in a node application. I'm using Postman form-data (like I have in so many other API testing situations) to post a message to my node application. But when I `console.log` the `request.body`, I get an empty object. Here is my entire node app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/foo',function(request,response){
    console.log(request.body);
});


app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

After posting some data, here is what shows in my console:

```
listening on *:3000
{}
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "api",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.12.4",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.5",
    "body-parser": "~1.12.0"
  }
}
```

I think I'd like to continue to use body parser because I plan on making this an API with json data. The app loads up just fine with no errors. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests, I found out that [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) is not able to parse `multipart/form-data` as they state on their README, which is the default encoding on Postman.

To parse this format, you can use: (from their README, again)

- [busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy#readme) and
  [connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-busboy#readme)
- [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multiparty#readme) and
  [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-multiparty#readme)
- [formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable#readme)
- [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer#readme)

If it's just for debugging purpose, set Postman to send either:

`x-www-form-encoded` by checking the appropriate checkbox (see picture)
[image: Check the "x-www-form-encoded" checkbox]

Or raw mode, being careful to set the mime header to `application/json` or the parser will ignore it (see picture)
[image: Check "raw" and don't forget to choose "application/json" as encoding]

Comment: That was it! I simply changed the posted body format and it works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am getting expected console outputs when I post data using postman and your code when setting the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. `npm-bodyparser` does not handle `multipart/form-data`, which is what you were posting.

To parse `multipart/form-data`, use `multer` or `busboy`.

Comment: That was it! I simply changed the posted body format and it works perfectly! Thanks!